# Most elegant way to access UINavigationController from pushed controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, software-design

Say I have
NavigationController->Root[Table View Controller subclass]
So from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of my Table View Controller subclass I have to push another view controller to NavigationController.

What is the most elegant way to access NavigationController? Should I use have delegate of NavigationController in my Table View Controller? Is this best approach if I have multiple tasks of accessing top object from hierarchy levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `self.navigationController`.

Comment: Things were much more easy that we imagine :) thx, will accept now